# How do i pull a list of the envelopes for the past 3 hours?

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

This is what i currently have, I have it trying to pull the past 3 hours but it seems to be pulling the last day

```
$fromDate = ((Get-Date).AddHours((-3)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssK"))
Write-Host $FromDate
try{
$(Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes" `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
    'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
  } `
    -Body @{ "from_date" = ${fromDate}; "Status" = "Completed" }).envelopes |Select-Object -property envelopeId -ExpandProperty envelopeId| out-file -filepath .\envelopes.txt 

}
```

Let me know what you think, maybe i'm missing something

I expected it to pull the last 3 hours but it seems to be pulling full days, it runs every 3 hours to pull the last 3 hours of completed documents

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted didn’t work but what did work was removing the extra pair of parentheses in  `.AddHours((-3))`

It should have been  `.AddHours(-3)`

Once that changed the issue was corrected and it pulled the last 3 hours only

Answer (score 0):

The `from_date` is a query parameter, not a JSON body, this is a GET call ,there's no body, you have to put this in the URL.

Should look something like this:

```
$fromDate = ((Get-Date).AddHours((-3)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssK"))
Write-Host $FromDate
try{
$(Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "${apiUri}/v2.1/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes?from_date=$fromDate&status=completed" `
    -Method 'GET' `
    -Headers @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $accessToken";
    'Content-Type'  = "application/json";
  } `
.envelopes |Select-Object -property envelopeId -ExpandProperty envelopeId| out-file -filepath .\envelopes.txt 

}
```